# Is there anyway to create RPM so that yum will allow two versions of the same package?

Tags: yum, packages, rpm

I'm creating two versions of an RPM and I want yum to keep the old versions when installing the new one. There is no conflicting files. Is this at possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the package name starts with `kernel`. Otherwise, [add the version as a suffix to the name of the old package](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines#Multiple_packages_with_the_same_base_name).

```
Name: foobar09
```

Comment: Thanks. I really don't want to change the name of the packages. I did not know about the kernel one. Fun, albeit pretty much useless in my case.